# How could I plot orbits of a dynamical system as in the image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am reading about Latex and I would like to know how to plot using tikZ the following image
[image]

$x_0$ should be an $\omega$-limit point of $x$
I was able to find out how to reach something similar to what i want, but it is not yet the same

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %\draw[-stealth] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below]{$x$};
  %\draw[-stealth] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[left]{$y$};
  \draw [rotate=-45, postaction=decorate, decoration={markings,
     mark=at position 0.93 with {\arrow{latex}}}]
     plot[domain=32:0, variable=\t, smooth, samples=75] ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t} and {0.004*\t*\t} );

  % Draw rotated ellipse (90 degrees)
  \begin{scope}[rotate=-45+90]
     \draw[blue, dashed] (0,0) ellipse ({1.5} and {0.75});
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I ve got is as follows [image]

But, to me, it does not really seem what I want as those curves should behave asymptotically as the blue ellipse. Also, how could i add those points and name them accordingly? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: I am a beginner, I do not really know how to even start with tikZ. I ve thought first i would need to find an ODE which approximately has the above phase portrait and try to plot it.

Comment: @Jack, kindly post some Tikz code. To achive your result, no ODE is needed. And if it should, you may just want to draw a parametrized curve with Tikz. There are several ways to achive your drawing. https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines , or here with code: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: @MS-SPO I have added code

Comment: @Jack, great. Adding a screenshot of your current result and a few words about remaining problems would be good. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[
rotate=45,
postaction=decorate,
decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.010 with {\coordinate (A);},
mark=at position 0.020 with {\arrow{Latex}},
mark=at position 0.340 with {\coordinate (B);},
mark=at position 0.350 with {\arrow{Latex}},
mark=at position 0.615 with {\coordinate (C);},
mark=at position 0.625 with {\arrow{Latex}},
mark=at position 0.844 with {\coordinate (D);},
mark=at position 0.854 with {\arrow{Latex}},
}] plot[domain=1360:0, variable=\t, samples=200] ({exp(0.0005*\t)*1.5*cos(\t)},{exp(0.0005*\t)*0.75*sin(\t)});
\draw[blue, thick, dashed, rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse ({1.5} and {0.75});
\foreach \c in {A,B,C,D}
  \fill (\c) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw[densely dotted] (C) -- (D);
\node (E) at (3,-2) {$\phi(t_1,x)$};
\draw[-Latex, shorten >=2pt] (E) to[out=160, in=-90, looseness=0.6] +(-1,0.5) to[out=90, in=-20, looseness=0.6] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Elliptic spiral with label and arrows]

*Edit:*

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[
rotate=45,
postaction=decorate,
decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.010 with {\coordinate (A);},
mark=at position 0.020 with {\arrow{Latex}},
mark=at position 0.340 with {\coordinate (B);},
mark=at position 0.350 with {\arrow{Latex}},
mark=at position 0.615 with {\coordinate (C);},
mark=at position 0.625 with {\arrow{Latex}},
mark=at position 0.844 with {\coordinate (D);},
mark=at position 0.854 with {\arrow{Latex}},
}] plot[domain=1360:0, variable=\t, samples=200] ({exp(0.0005*\t)*1.5*cos(\t)},{exp(0.0005*\t)*0.75*sin(\t)});
\draw[blue, thick, dashed, rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse ({1.5} and {0.75});
\path[rotate=45] ({1.5*cos(-75)},{0.75*sin(-75)}) coordinate (E);
\foreach \c in {A,B,C,D,E}
  \fill (\c) circle[radius=1.2pt];
\draw[densely dotted] (C) -- (D);
\node (F) at (3,-2) {$\phi(t_1,x)$};
\draw[-Latex, shorten >=2pt] (F) to[out=160, in=-90, looseness=0.6] +(-1,0.5) to[out=90, in=-20, looseness=0.6] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Elliptic spiral with label and arrows]

Comment: Thank you, @hperkristiansen. Any idea how could I also add those labeled points as in the picture?

Comment: How can I plot another collinear dot on the blue ellipse? @hpekristiansen